# How to interact with stdout.pipe(process.stdout) NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Can someone help me with this?
I'm trying to spawn a process and interact with it.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

function runTask(params) {
  const task = params.split(' ')
  let file = task[0]
  if (file === 'npm') {
    file = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'npm.cmd' : file
  }
  const data = spawn(file, task.slice(1))
  data.stdout.pipe(process.stdout, { end: false })
}

runTask('npm init vite testingvite')
```

It did show me the stdout, but I can't interact with it.

Is it even possible to do this?

OS: Windows10, Node: 12, NPM: 6

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe `process.stdin` to the child's `stdin`. Note here `child.stdin` is writable while `child.stdout` and `child.stderr` are readable.

Here's my example to interact with the child's standard input. By the way I'm not sure if the `wc` command is available on windows machine. I'm running it on ubuntu.

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const child = spawn("wc");

process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);

child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(`child stdout:\n${data}`);
});
// Press Ctrl-D to end the input and get the result of the "wc" cmd.
```